# Content of list-elements full height CSS only

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm still struggling with my lists...

With some help I managed to get a horizontal list with (for my case) perfect dimension: 33.33% width and the same height based on the highest element.
I combined regular list-items with `table` and `table-cell` properties.

However, now I just need to wrap the content of every `<li>`-element in an `<a>`-tag to make the whole `<li>` a link. This is harder than I thought, since the links won't fill the whole `<li>`-element according to the highest one.

The best is, if you take a look at the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paelzersebbi/mJm6p/4/

The red part need to be extended to the bottom of each `<li>`-element. I cannot use fixed height or width since it needs to be responsive. I also need the `<div class="one">`-container since it is supposed to have a background-image.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="caption"><h4>Caption 1</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            Here is some text.
        </div>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="caption"><h4>Caption 2</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            Here is some text.<br />
            But there is more.
        </div>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="">
        <div class="one">
            <div class="caption"><h4>Caption 3</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            Here is some text.<br />
            But there is more.<br />
            And even more.
        </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 30px 0;
    width: calc(80% + 60px);
    margin: 0 -30px;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.33333%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
a {
    display: block;
    background: red;
}
a:hover {
    background: #CCC;
}
.one {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #C92;
    position: relative;
}
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
h4 {
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}
.two {
    padding:5px;
}
```

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use pseudo elements on `<a>` to increase its area where it can be reached by click/hover. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mJm6p/6/)**

---

update to your CSS.

```
a {
    display: block;
    background: red;/* demo purpose */
    position:relative;/* needed for absolute pseudo */
}
li {
    overflow:hidden;/* hide pseudo overflowing */
}
a:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:400px;/* whatever you think will be high enough */
    background:inherit;/* demo purpose */
}
```

---

Other option is to use this structure: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mJm6p/7/)**

```
<nav> <a> tags </a> <a> tags </a> <a> tags </a> </nav>
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks! Most of the time I completely forget about the pseudo-elements... they can be really useful.